# Is it possible to add header to TabHost in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to add header to TabHost in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can, but can't test it for you. If you look at [the manual](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) you see an xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I suggest you add your header view above the TabHost part, so something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<yourView goes here/>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    [....]
</TabHost>
```

It would be quick to try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

i have an error when i try that . At the start of tabHost.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.dnielf.hello.compounds.Header
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/header_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
android:text="Cevichito4Dummies"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:typeface="sans"/>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

SOLUTION : the solution was wrap all with a linearlayout ( include its attributes )